# Postfix Algorithm Evaluation in JS

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, postfix-mta, postfix-notation

this is what we start with: `'7.7+7'`
The input of the function is an array of strings (original input converted to postfix): `7.7,7,+`

then would get fed back into another function in order to display within my html page. this function is nested in another parent function to call with class object.

```js
this.postfixEval = function(postfixArray){
        var stack = new Stack();

        for( element of postfixArray){
            console.log("element: " + element);

            if(isNaN(element)){
                var x = stack.pop();
                var y = stack.pop();
                console.log("var x/y: " + x + " " + y + " element: " + element) ;
                if (element == "+"){
                    result = (y+x);
                    console.log("Expected Result: " + result)
                    stack.push(y + x);
                } else if (element == '-'){
                    stack.push(y - x);
                } else if (element == '*'){
                    stack.push(y * x);
                } else if (element == '/'){
                    stack.push(y / x);
                }
            } else {
                stack.push( parseFloat(element) );
            }
        }
        //final check for non numbers within the stack
        var returnValue = null;
        while( !stack.isEmpty() ){
            stack.print();
            var element = stack.pop();  
            if(isNaN(element)){
                continue;
            } else{
                returnValue = element;
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong? the output is simply 7.7. Here is a sample of the logging in attempt to debug:

```
scripts.js:75 postFix: 7.7,7,+ 
scripts.js:145 undefined
scripts.js:175 element: 7.7
scripts.js:175 element: 7
scripts.js:175 element: + 
scripts.js:180 var x/y: 7 7.7 element: + 
scripts.js:76 result: null
```

Thank you for your time and help in advance.

Comment: Correction: _then would get fed back into another function in order to display **edit: The Result** within my html page. this function is nested in another parent function to call with class object_

Comment: When I run your code in Node, with the "stack" as an array instead of your Stack type, your code works fine.

Comment: @Pointy exactly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I replace your `new Stack` with a simple array, and make the necessary adjustments to accommodate that change, I get the correct answer...

```js
function postfixEval( postfixArray ) {
        var stack = [];

        for( element of postfixArray){
            console.log("element: " + element);

            if(isNaN(element)){
                var x = stack.pop();
                var y = stack.pop();
                console.log("var x/y: " + x + " " + y + " element: " + element) ;
                if (element == "+"){
                    result = (y+x);
                    console.log("Expected Result: " + result)
                    stack.push(y + x);
                } else if (element == '-'){
                    stack.push(y - x);
                } else if (element == '*'){
                    stack.push(y * x);
                } else if (element == '/'){
                    stack.push(y / x);
                }
            } else {
                stack.push( parseFloat(element) );
            }
        }
        //final check for non numbers within the stack
        var returnValue = null;
        while( stack.length > 0 ){
            console.log( stack );
            var element = stack.pop();  
            if(isNaN(element)){
                continue;
            } else{
                returnValue = element;
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
    
postfixEval(['7.7','7','+']);
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help! I have had the great help of https://stackoverflow.com/users/6739159/kpjvideo  found the problem that was occuring in how the input was being processed so then it made the input of this function to be null instead of the function itself. I did get to simplify my code thanks to yours, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach:

```
const value = '2 3 * 1 - 5 /';

function postfixEval( expr ) {
    let stack = [];
    const arr = expr.split('').filter((el)=>el !== " " )
    console.log( arr );
    for( element of arr){

        console.log("element: " + element);

        if(isNaN(element)){
            var y = stack.pop();
            var x = stack.pop();
            const result = eval(x+element+y)
            stack.push(result)
            console.log( result );  
        } else {
            stack.push( parseFloat(element) );
        }
    }
        console.log( typeof stack[0] );
    return stack[0];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks a lot @holydragon I will edit it with the explanation when I got free time.

Answer (score 0):

Lee SEE My Approach

function evaluatePostfix(exp)
{

```
    let stack=[];
    
    
    for(let i=0;i<exp.length;i++)
    {
        let c=exp[i];
        
        
        if(! isNaN( parseInt(c) ))
        stack.push(c.charCodeAt(0) - '0'.charCodeAt(0));
        
        
        else
        {
            let val1 = stack.pop();
            let val2 = stack.pop();
            
            switch(c)
            {
                case '+':
                stack.push(val2+val1);
                break;
                
                case '-':
                stack.push(val2- val1);
                break;
                
                case '/':
                stack.push(val2/val1);
                break;
                
                case '*':
                stack.push(val2*val1);
                break;
        }
        }
    }
    return stack.pop();
```

}

let exp="121*+2-";
document.write("postfix evaluation: "+evaluatePostfix(exp));

Comment: What is `stack.push(c.charCodeAt(0) - '0'.charCodeAt(0));` doing?